# Fresh Ubuntu install unable to connect to IPv4 addresses

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ipv6, ipv4

I just recently made a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on my newly built desktop. However I'm having some internet connectivity issues. Please bare with me as I am a linux noob.

Anyway, I'm unable to connect to many websites but CAN connect to google, facebook, wikipedia, fast.com...What do they all have in common? They're reachable via IPv6.

When I try to curl -v reddit.com, it tries to connect to their IPv4 address but fails. When I do the same with google, it connects to their IPv6 address fine and everything proceeds swimmingly.

It is to note that I am working with an Apple Time Capsule right now, but as per a post yesterday I ended up ordering another router and plan on replacing it on Friday. That might be the problem, but I don't see a reason why it would be.

My roommate who is running Linux Mint can access IPv4 addresses fine, so I'm thinking it's got to do something with my configuration. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated because I'm getting extremely frustrated.

Comment: If you could try out http://ds.test-ipv6.com/ and http://test-ipv6.netiter.dk/ on both machines and share the results, I think that might help a bit towards understanding the problem. The output from `route` and `route -6` could also be useful in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Ubuntu. That indeed sounds like an odd issue, especially with a fresh install. A couple quick troubleshooting steps:

- Reboot ... sorry, had to say it.
- Also reboot the router - power down all networking equipment. Start up modem and wait a minute, then power up router and wait, then finally power on your machine. This gives you the greatest likelihood that each component is playing nicely with its neighbors.
- Determine whether the issue persists when using an ethernet cable, or only with Wi-Fi. This could point towards an issue with DHCP, maybe an issue with the modem, maybe an issue with Wi-Fi signal.

Good luck!

Comment: I'll reboot everything and see if that's the problem. My desktop does not have a WiFi connection but can only be wired.

Comment: Hmm, is your roommate using Wi-Fi? Maybe have them try a network cable? I find it odd that you are having this issue while it's fine on another machine. I assume it's fine for mobile devices on Wi-Fi?

Comment: He is also using a wired connection.

Comment: Ok. That was a shot in the dark. Short of reinstalling, another thing I would try is, if possible, use your machine on another network. That might be tricky since you have no Wi-Fi, but yeah, if the machine works on another network, that indicates that the issue is with your network, versus an Ubuntu configuration.

Comment: Also check your `/etc/network/interfaces`. I have seen new installs where the installer only configured IPv6 because that's what it saw first during the install.

Answer (score 0):

On Kubuntu 18.04, I had the same problem, solved with configure static ip address in /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml (path specitic to Ubuntu 17.10 and more recent). I ignore if the problem comes from there but I precise that I've two ethernet ports on my motherboard.

**Important : you have to remplace "ens33" bellow by your interface name, and  comupter ip, gateway and DNS of your choice.**

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   ens33:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Exit and save your changes by running the commands below :

```
sudo netplan apply
```

source : https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/

**VictoSab**